# I wonder if RStudio Server installation is absolutely necessary to run shiny-server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have installed R and shiny-server on linux to use shiny.

However, the following error message is displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HExM7.png)

> An error has occurred
>
> The application failed to start.
>
> Connection attempt was absorted.

I wonder if RStudio Server installation is absolutely necessary to run shiny-server.

Comment: RStudio Server should not be required to run shiny-server. Those are two very different things. How exactly did you attempt to deploy? What exact OS and version number are you using? Did you install R itself first? Maybe check the [error logs](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003717168-Shiny-Server-Error-Logs) for more details. You really haven't given us a lot of info to go on here to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help. | 

How exactly did you attempt to deploy?
=> I installed shiny-server on Linux after installing R. | 

What exact OS and version number are you using?
=> CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) | 

Did you install R itself first?
=> Yes | 

Maybe check the error logs for more details. | 
<hello-shiny-*-*-*.log> <rmd-shiny-*-*-*.log>
su: ignore --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive to --login.
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘shiny’
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Comment: Well, the error "there is no package called ‘shiny’" indicates that that the shiny package is not installed for the R version on the machine. Some sample directions here: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-shiny-server-on-centos-7/. You need the step like `sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown', 'devtools', 'RJDBC'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""`